# Validation(ASP.net):Attribute 'placeholder' is not a valid attribute of element 'TextBox'

Tags: c#, asp.net

I keep getting the placeholder error since i run the web application in my registration page. I am also trying to sanitize data in the class page also. Below are my codes for the layout page and class page. May i know what is wrong with the codes?

LAYOUT

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/TopJobAgency.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Register.aspx.cs" Inherits="TopJobAgencyApp.Register" %>

<%@ Register assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagprefix="asp" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <link href="/css/Register.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <div class="container">
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-6 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-offset-3">

                <form id="form1" runat="server">
                    <h2>Please Sign Up <small>It's free and always will be.</small></h2>

                    <hr class="colorgraph">

                    <div class="form-group">

                        <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
                        </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>

                        <asp:TextBox ID="tbxDisplayname" Cssclass="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Username" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">

                        <asp:TextBox ID="tbxEmailaddress" Cssclass="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Email Address" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="tbxPw" Cssclass="form-control" placeholder="Password" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:PasswordStrength ID="tbxPw_PasswordStrength" runat="server" TargetControlID="tbxPw">
                                </asp:PasswordStrength>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="tbxCfmpw" Cssclass="form-control" placeholder="Retype Password" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:PasswordStrength ID="tbxCfmpw_PasswordStrength" runat="server" TargetControlID="tbxCfmpw">
                                </asp:PasswordStrength>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                                        <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-9 col-md-9">
                            By clicking <strong class="label label-primary">Register</strong>, you agree to the <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#t_and_c_m">Terms and Conditions</a> set out by this site, including our Cookie Use.
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <hr class="colorgraph">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                            <asp:Button ID="btnRegister" runat="server" Cssclass="btn btn-primary btn-block" Text="Register" OnClick="btnRegister_Click1" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                            <asp:Button ID="btnBack" runat="server" Cssclass="btn btn-default btn-block" Text="Back" OnClick="btnBack_Click" />
                        </div>
                        <br />
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="t_and_c_m" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Terms & Conditions</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        The use of this website is subject to the following terms of use:
                        <br /><br />
                        The content of the pages of this website is for your general information and use only. It is subject to change without notice.<br />
                        This website uses cookies to monitor browsing preferences. If you do allow cookies to be used, the following personal information may be stored by us for use by third parties: [insert list of information].<br />
                        Neither we nor any third parties provide any warranty or guarantee as to the accuracy, timeliness, performance, completeness or suitability of the information and materials found or offered on this website for any particular purpose. You acknowledge that such information and materials may contain inaccuracies or errors and we expressly exclude liability for any such inaccuracies or errors to the fullest extent permitted by law.<br />
                        Your use of any information or materials on this website is entirely at your own risk, for which we shall not be liable. It shall be your own responsibility to ensure that any products, services or information available through this website meet your specific requirements.<br />
                        This website contains material which is owned by or licensed to us. This material includes, but is not limited to, the design, layout, look, appearance and graphics. Reproduction is prohibited other than in accordance with the copyright notice, which forms part of these terms and conditions.<br />
                        All trade marks reproduced in this website which are not the property of, or licensed to, the operator are acknowledged on the website.<br />
                        Unauthorised use of this website may give rise to a claim for damages and/or be a criminal offence.<br />
                        From time to time this website may also include links to other websites. These links are provided for your convenience to provide further information. They do not signify that we endorse the website(s). We have no responsibility for the content of the linked website(s).
                        Your use of this website and any dispute arising out of such use of the website is subject to the laws of Singapore, Temasek Polytechnic and Group 1.
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.modal-content -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal -->
    </div>
</asp:Content>

CLASS

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using TopJobAgencyApp.Class;
namespace TopJobAgencyApp
{
    public partial class Register : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect("Login.aspx?");
        }

        protected void btnRegister_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string user = tbxDisplayname.Text;
            string email = tbxEmailaddress.Text;
            string pw = tbxPw.Text;

            string querystring = "username=" + user;
            querystring += "&" + "email=" + email;
            querystring += "&" + "password=" + pw;

            Sanitize(user);
            Sanitize(email);
            Sanitize(pw);

            Registration u = new Registration(tbxDisplayname.Text, tbxEmailaddress.Text, tbxPw.Text);
            DBManager.InsertLogin(u);

            Response.Redirect("Login.aspx?");
        }

        protected void btnBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect("Home.aspx?");
        }
        public string Sanitize(string stringValue)
        {
            if (null == stringValue)
            {
                return stringValue;
            }
            else
            {
                RegexReplace(stringValue, "-{2,}", "_");
                RegexReplace(stringValue, @"(;|\s)(exec|execute|select|insert|update|delete|create|alter|drop|rename|truncate|backup|restore)\s", string.Empty, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                RegexReplace(stringValue, "_", string.Empty);
                RegexReplace(stringValue, @"[*/]+", string.Empty);
                return stringValue;
            }
        }
        private string RegexReplace(string stringValue, string matchPattern, string toReplaceWith)
        {
            return Regex.Replace(stringValue, matchPattern, toReplaceWith);
        }
        private string RegexReplace(string stringValue, string matchPattern, string toReplaceWith, RegexOptions regexOptions)
        {
            return Regex.Replace(stringValue, matchPattern, toReplaceWith, regexOptions);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The textbox server control doesn't have a placeholder attribute. The textbox doesn't support it and will generate an error when you attempt to set it since there is no property. You could possibly add it as an attribute in codehebind, or use a jQuery plugin.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: @MarkFitzpatrick That is only partially correct. You can add attributes to HTML elements at will in the ASPX markup, and they will be rendered on the client side. They do not have to line up to a specific property on the control. At some point, the behavior of Visual Studio changed so that it wouldn't complain when you add these attributes, though I can't remember exactly when that happened.

Comment: You say 'modal-dialog' on your code, how your open that with javascript, probably your javascript code render it outside `form` element.